# ElasticSearch use run-time analyzer with bool search query

Tags: elasticsearch

I have the bool search query for ElasticSearch like below:

```
{'query': {'bool': {'should': [{'wildcard': {'name': '*21age-s21*'}}]}}}
```

I used dynamic mapping, and the Standard Analyzer was used. It probably broke the string into `21age, s21` so search for `21age-s21` can't be found.

Can I add a run time Keyword Analyzer to my search query?  How should I do it?

Answer (score 1):

You are using dynamic mapping, so your index mapping will look like this

```
{
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "name": {
        "type": "text",
        "fields": {
          "keyword": {
            "type": "keyword",
            "ignore_above": 256
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Elasticsearch will use the standard analyzer if no analyzer is specified, which will break the string into the following tokens

```
{
  "tokens": [
    {
      "token": "21age",
      "start_offset": 0,
      "end_offset": 5,
      "type": "<ALPHANUM>",
      "position": 0
    },
    {
      "token": "s21",
      "start_offset": 6,
      "end_offset": 9,
      "type": "<ALPHANUM>",
      "position": 1
    }
  ]
}
```

You need to add .keyword to the name field. This uses the keyword analyzer instead of the standard analyzer (notice the ".keyword" after the `name` field). try out the below search query

```
{
  "query": {
    "term": {
      "name.keyword": "21age-s21"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: @user1187968 did you get a chance to go through the answer, looking forward to get feedback from you 

Comment: @user1187968 if you don't have any follow-up questions and the answer helped you resolve the issue, then please accept and upvote the answer. TIA :-)